# apt - Command line option 'i' [from -info] is not understood in combination with the other options

Tags: apt, cat, parameter

I was making a shell script with that installs packages from a list. The code looks like this:

```
apps="$(cat ./foo/bar/packages.txt)"
apt install $apps
```

But, I get the error

> E: Command line option 'i' [from -info] is not understood in combination with the other options.

The `packages.txt` looks like the following all on one line:

```
accountsservice acl acpi-support acpid ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see no `-i` option, are you sure that this is the code that you tested?

Comment: It's likely your `packages.txt` file has an entry `-info` in it and this is being interpreted as an option.   Perhaps a rogue space (eg `foo -info` rather than `foo-info` ?)  If you _want_ to have that interpreted as a package name then do `apt -- install $apps`.

Comment: Hmm... @StephenHarris after adding --install I now get `E: Command line option --install is not understood in combination with the other options
` I am searching packages.txt for -info now

Comment: You did `--install`; I wrote `-- install` - that space is important :-)  The `--` on its own typically means "end of options" so anything beginning with a `-` that follows it won't be interpreted as one

Comment: @StephenHarris Ahh! I see... After running cat `./.distromovetemp/extract/packages.txt | grep "info"`
 I found `... initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core initscripts inputattach insserv -info intel-gpu...` I'm about to try your suggestion...

Comment: Well, the `-info` entry is wrong.  The `apt -- install` will fail to install a package called that.  You need to fix your package list.

Comment: @StephenHarris Your suggestion worked! I will be delighted for you to post your suggestion as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a call like this is that bad data in the `packages.txt` file can cause breakage.

In this case you have an entry in the file `-info`.  This means the command you are running will look like

```
apt install pkg1 pkg2 ... -info pkg10 pkg11 ...
```

The `-info` will be interpreted as an option to the `apt` command.  It doesn't like this and so reports `Command line option 'i' [from -info] is not understood`.

You can prevent words like this being interpreted by putting a `--` before the install

```
apt -- install $apps
```

The `--` means "no more options" and so the `-info` will now be understood to be a package name.  This is a good thing to do when using unknown input.

But you still need to fix your `packages.txt` file to remove the bad entry.